# How to clean \xc2\xa0 using tf.strings.regex_replace?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, regexp-replace

I tried the the following but does not work:

```
tf.strings.regex_replace(_string, "\xc2\xa0", ' ')
```

or

```
tf.strings.regex_replace(_string, "\%xc2\%xa0", ' ')
```

But both don't work. the python string replace method should work but as part of tf.data.Dataset pipeline that can potentially part of a model layer, i will have to use tf.string.replace(...). I also could do the string processing outside of tf pipeline but it is not elegant/robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works
tf.strings.regex_replace(_string, '[\xc2\xa0]', ' ')